# Finding the period of a linear combination of sines and cosines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, periodic-functions

I have found by trial that the period of a linear combination of sine and cosine functions is seemingly always at most $2\pi$. This is for functions in the form $\sin nx+\cos mx$ where the coefficient of x is an integer. Does this property hold for any combination of sines and cosines and what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Have you tried using $\sin nx=\cos(nx-\pi/2)$?